# Why github collaborator can still push to private repo when there is a mismatch between local email config and the email setup in github?

Tags: git, github, version-control

For a private repository only open to collaborators, I found even a collaborator does not use his email setup in github, if he clone the repository to local, then he can still push something to the repository.

Git log shows something like `Author: username <user@MacBook-Pro.local>` and in the commit message, the avatar is grey. I know this indicates a mismatch between the local and github email:
[Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user)

However, in access settings, the access is only open to the email setup in Github. How does such push complete? Does this mean any computer with the invitation email can push something to the repo, in other words, is the access not limited to the only email? If that is true, in my view this is somehow dangerous for a repo.

I tried to search questions like "how does the link between git local repo and remote one work", but most results are simple tutorial for building connection, which do not reveal the deeper mechanism.

Comment: this is normally controlled through ssh keys. In your github account you can upload the public key, and then when you push you unlock your private key which signs the commit as being from that account.

Comment: [the git manual on ssh keys](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key) - but instead of 'email to administrator' you find `Settings > SSH Keys > Add SSH key` in bitbucket, gitlab, github or whatever host you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate identities :

1. the author and the editor (committer) of a commit
2. the credentials used to communicate with GitHub

The first one is written in the history of your commits, and is taken from the `user.name` and `user.email` in the git config when someone created a new commit on his machine.

The second one is represented either by the login provided when pushing through https, or by the ssh key when pushing through ssh.

---

If you push (say : with your ssh key) a commit created by someone else, the push succeeds, and yet the commit is linked to "someone else".

---

Do you have reasons to believe the *push* was performed by a revoked user ?

If so, this means he still has access to a login/password or an ssh key that allows him to push ; you can fix this by changing the password, or by revoking the incriminated ssh key and generating a new one.

Otherwise : it is a matter of inspecting the git history, and deciding it the "author" field of some commits should be edited or not.
Note that actions such as `git rebase`, `git cherry-pick` and `git commit --amend` keep the original author by default.

Answer (score 1):

As LeGEC mentioned, there are two separate things going on here.

First, a commit has an author and committer, and each of those identities has a name (usually a personal name, not a username) and an email.  GitHub associates a commit with a user based on the email matching their account.  If the commit emails don't match any account, you get a generic avatar.

Second, when you push commits, there is some sort of authentication on the repository, and for GitHub, the actor is going to either be a user, some sort of integration or bot, or a deploy key.

Note that these are not related.  If you have push access to a repository, you can push commits from any user with any (well-formed) name and email.  This is important because in some projects, such as Git itself, commits are collected by a maintainer who then pushes them to the main repository.  Some of those contributors may not have a GitHub account, and the pushes still need to work.

The most likely answer here is that your contributor has misconfigured (or just not configured) their Git settings properly, and as such are creating commits with an email address linked to the local machine, which they then push with their valid credentials.

If so, you should talk to your contributor and tell them to set `user.name` to their personal (human) name and `user.email` to a valid email associated with their GitHub account.  GitHub provides undeliverable addresses that they can find in the settings if they don't want to expose a real email.

Note that [`user.name` has no effect on authentication](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatshouldIputincodeusernamecode) and therefore is usually not a username.

Comment: Nice complement to LeGEC's answer!